# Secure PHP login against replay attacks

Tags: php, security, encryption, hash

Until now I have always been using md5 and sha1 to encrypt the passwords in my PHP logins, but as these algorithms are now considered outdated and not secure anymore, I want to build a new login system with the PHP functions [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). There is, however, one thing that I cannot find a solution for with these functions: In order to make the login safe against replay attacks, it is not enough for me to just have an individual salt for every password. Because if an attacker somehow eavesdrops the communication between the client and the server, he can just send the user name and the already encrypted password hash to the server just like the original client did. So my solution has always been to create an additional "salt" (I don't know if there is an official term for what I mean) that is only valid for one single login attempt. So the client gets the two salts from the server (one is always the same for each user account, the other one different each time), encrypts the password the user enters and sends the hash to the server. The server then checks this hash (e.g. $Hash == sha1($HashFromDbWithFixedSalt . $RandomHash)). Then a new $RandomHash is created. So even if the attacker imitates the user's communication there is no way for him to gain unallowed access.

The new PHP functions do support a salt, but I could not find a way to implement my old solution with these two, because the hash in the DB would contain the fixed hash (different for each user account) but not the random hash (only valid for one attempt). Does anyone have an idea or maybe already solved this problem?

**EDIT:**

This is how I used to do it:

A new user registers:

1. Create a random salt for this user.
2. Save md5($password_in_cleartext + $salt) and the salt itself to database.

The user wants to login:

1. The user sends his user name to the server
2. The server looks up his salt from the database and creates an additional random salt that it saves in the $_SESSION. It sends those two salts to the user.
3. The user encrypts his password on the client (via JS) like this: sha1(md5($password_in_cleartext + $salt_from_the_db) + $random_salt). He sends this hash to the server.
4. The server checks if sha1($hash_from_the_db + $random_salt) == $hash_the_user_sent. If they are not equal, it creates a new random_salt and sends it to the user (back to step 3).

Comment: The best way is SSL, like @samlev said!

Comment: Hashing the password on the client isn't encryption. If anything it makes everything *less* secure, because it reduces the possible search space for an attacker. Use SSL to protect the communication between the client and the server (that *is* encryption), then hash their raw password with something like BCrypt.

Comment: Another note: in bcrypt, the salt is *part of the hashed password*. I know that this sounds less secure, but it's really not.

Comment: You can use self-signed SSL certificates. It will throw trust errors in your browser, but it still works (and it's free).

Comment: Yes yes, I have used self-signed SSL certificates before but I am really just interested if there is a way to do it myself. Anything else is probably a waste of time as I doubt anyone is ever actually going to attack my platform. So maybe I should have asked like this: Would there theoretically be a way to do this, are there any creative patchwork solutions?

Comment: "Until now I have always been using md5 and sha1 to encrypt the passwords in my PHP logins" No you haven't. [MD5 and SHA1 are not encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded)

Comment: @DennisP. - "Anything else is probably a waste of time as I doubt anyone is ever actually going to attack my platform."  Famous last words.  ALWAYS assume that your platform is going to be attacked.  The infrastructure you write will be MUCH more resilient as a result of taking a strong security stance.

Comment: By the way, MD5 is completely BROKEN and has been for several years now and SHA-1 is partially broken.  Cryptographic hash primitives are supposed to ONLY be used as data fingerprints, NOT for storing passwords.  Also, mixing hashes is a significant indicator that someone does not understand actual security.  Writing a login system is a highly complex and advanced topic that should not be attempted by new programmers.  Use a prepackaged system such as the one I maintain:  http://barebonescms.com/documentation/sso/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not using SSL then your login will not be secure. It doesn't matter how irreversible the hashing algorithms you use are, there are too many other ways to compromise the interaction.

And its not the size of your hash, its what you do with it that matters. A well written system using md5 will be more secure than a badly written one using sha2.

Assuming that you are already using SSL and HSTS with pre-registration, and some cacheable ssl-stripping-sensitive CSS but still want more security, or your running on a shared server with remote SSL termination, then your current approach is valid, you just need to upgrade your hashing algorithm (and the space allocated for storing the hashed password). But as you've found, you still need to reply the storage salt + password hash before applying the session salt hash (hint: the session id is a good source of entropy for the latter but the session value should not be accessible to JavaScript - generate a has of the session id serverside to use as the session salt). The problem then becomes what hash functions are available in JavaScript.

Comment: Cool, thank you, that is very interesting! So I would use password_hash(), or even the underlying crypt() function, but instead of verifying the password with password_verify() I would just manually compare the hashes like I used to (where one would be the one from the database+session salt and the other one generated by JavaScript on the client)?

Comment: Crypt only knows about a single tier of hashing - using the stored salt. So you can't use it to verify a password that has been hashed twice.

Comment: Of course I can ;-). Both my PHP backend and the client know both salts. So, the client first hashes the password with the storage salt. The resulting hash will be exactly the same one like in the database. Then, it hashes this hash again with the session salt. Then the PHP backend hashes the hash from the db with the session salt. Violà, the both resulting hashes should be exactly the same if the user enters the correct password.

Comment: While I'd agree, on the surface, that a well written system that uses md5 would be better than a badly written one using sha2, a well written one using bcrypt would beat both. The Question asker gets it right; neither md5 or sha* are the correct solution for storing passwords at rest these days.

Using the users password in login cookies is always a bad idea, especially when you're using weak hashing methods. This is how 12 million passwords on the Ashey Madison site were broken; the login cookie used md5 combined with their plain-text password, despite the password being stored as bcrypt.

Answer (score 4):

`password_hash` will generate a salt automatically for each password.

The hashed password should never be passed back to the user or leave the server. If you're concerned about traffic sniffing, or [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack), use SSL/https.

It sounds like you're also trying to protect against [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attacks. In this case, you would set a random token when the user hits the page the first time, and expect it to be sent with every request (this will stop sites which don't have access to the token from sending requests on behalf of the user).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not really what I meant. I edited my original post, hopefully this is helpful ;-). Oh, and I don't want to use SSL because it costs additional money and I believe there has to be another way.

Comment: @DennisP. It might not be want you meant, but it's what you want. Don't try to invent your own security protocol unless you really really know what you are doing, you'll just end up making it weaker.

Comment: SSL is not that [expensive](https://www.ssls.com/). What are you trying to protect @DennisP.? There is *no other way*.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - SSL is free if you know where to look:  https://www.startssl.com/  If you are doing stuff locally, then you can create and use your own Certificate Authority and then create and sign your own certs (again, for free).